# What is the difference when inject the dependency in different place in directive in angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

All:

If I define a directive like:

```
[1] Inject $dependency in at the directive function:
app.directive("sampledirective", function( $dependency ){
                return {
                    restrict:"AE",
                    scope: {},
                    replace: true,
                    templateUrl: "tmpl/trendtopic.html",
                    controller: function($scope){

                    }
                };

            });



[2] Inject $dependency in at the controller function:
app.directive("sampledirective", function(  ){
                return {
                    restrict:"AE",
                    scope: {},
                    replace: true,
                    templateUrl: "tmpl/trendtopic.html",
                    controller: function($scope, $dependency){

                    }
                };

            });
```

I wonder which way is right and/or which is suggested?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are equivalent, since services are singletons. You would need the first one if you wanted to use the dependency in the directive's link function (or any other directive function).

If the controller needs the dependency, I would inject the dependency in the controller, and not in the directive. That allows moving the controller to its own file, outside of the directive, and thus make it easily testable.

Comment: Thanks, so your suggestion about controller is to define any controller out side the directive and just pass it in when use it in a directive? I do not have experience in JS testing, that is why I am not familiar with the pattern to design controller and directive. Any suggested link to learn the testing you are talking about?

Comment: Yes. You can simply pass the *name* of the controller to the directive. I learnt how to test angular applications by reading the documentation of angular, jasmine and karma.